# Compare Two Textbox Values and Show Error in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two textboxes like this.

```
   <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"Height="20"  Name="OldTextBox" Text="{Binding OldName}"  />

<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"  Name="NewTextBox"  Text="{Binding NewName}"  />
```

If OldName and NewName are different, I want to show both textbox values in Red color.

I am following MVVM. Is it better to do it in ViewModel or any simple foreground style ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform that kind of validation you can have your view-model class implement `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

```
class MyViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string NewName { get; set; } // Notify property change here
    public string OldName { get; set; } // Notify property change here
    public string Error { get; private set; }
    public string this[string property]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (property)
            {
                case "OldName":
                case "NewName":
                    return OldName != NewName ? "Names are different" : null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to enable validation in your bindings:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"Height="20"  Name="OldTextBox" Text="{Binding OldName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  />
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"  Name="NewTextBox"  Text="{Binding NewName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  />
```

If needed, you can change the background color by styling your textboxes:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```